# ASP.NET Core pipelines from within the same main application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to run parallel ASP.NET Core pipelines from within the same main application. I want to expose an endpoint for external consumers and would like to register only few services for that endpoint  when compared to main application. Is there any way to properly do it in asp.net core?

I could see a similar implementation here and it is almost 2 yrs old. Is there a better way to do it? Or is it the only way right now?

https://www.strathweb.com/2017/04/running-multiple-independent-asp-net-core-pipelines-side-by-side-in-the-same-application/

Comment: From the comments on that page, it looks like this has been included in the package WebApiContrib.Core. (see https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib.Core/ParallelApplicationPipelinesExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 0):

So, what problem in this solution? You can use Map, MapWhen, UseBranchWithServices. It's good solution.

One more point is to try create two hosts in main. But I not realy enshure that it can be implemented.

One another solution, you can create independent app and setup nginx (iis) in the front of 2 instances. Then you get the independent pipeline, independent configuration, you can deploy it to different machines and so on. 
But when you change the code you should redeploy 2 applications in the same time.

So, you should answer on question: is it should be independent part of system, you you want to some small specific configuration for this API.

If you need first variant please use another instance, if second - use MapWhen, UseBranchWithServices and so one.